# Можно ли ускорить выполнение кода?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Всем привет. Есть такой метод, который вставляет N значений в БД. Проблема, очень долго работает с большими значениями ~500_000. Вопрос, можно ли как то ускорить выполнение метода?

```
public static void paste(int n,String fieldName, String tableName) {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT "+fieldName+" FROM "+tableName);
            if (rs.next()) {
                stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM "+tableName+" WHERE "+fieldName+" >0");
            }
            PreparedStatement pState = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+tableName+" ("+fieldName+") VALUES (?)");
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                pState.setInt(1, i);
                pState.executeUpdate();
            }
            System.out.println("Я заполнил " + n + " строк");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка с заполнением таблицы!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: почитайте про batch insert

Comment: Гораздо разумнее первым запросом создать хранимую процедуру, которая выполнит все требуемые операции, вторым её выполнить, третьим удалить. И никакие итерации не нужны - пусть сервер этим занимается.

Comment: Akina, пожалуйста, можно поподробнее? Я еще совсем зеленый в этом деле.

Comment: В зависимости от того что на самом деле надо сделать, тут могут быть разные варианты. То что сверху достаточно удалить все поля у которых fieldname > n  и добавить новых от max(fieldName) до n.